# How to separate Jena model and SPARQL query in different methods()

Tags: methods, program-entry-point

I have ontology loaded in Jena model. In Jena code, after creation of model and load the ontology, I want multiple Sparql queries run against the ontology. 
So in main() method, I will create the model and read the ontology, how can I then run multiple queries. 
Will I have a separate method() for each sparql query?
Kindly guide me how can I modularize the code?

regards

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make the methods accept a model as an argument and then pass the generated model. for example:

```
       public static void execQ(String queryString, Model model) {
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        for (; results.hasNext(); ) {
            QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
            RDFNode x = soln.get("varName"); // Get a result variable by name. 
            Resource r = soln.getResource("VarR"); // Get a result variable - must be a resource 
            Literal l = soln.getLiteral("VarL"); // Get a result variable - must be a literal 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you djodjo, can you come with a short example? I will really appreciate because I am new to the environment and just need a clue to start.

Comment: I edited my answer. It is super simple and quite general but you can manage different levels of abstraction depending on your queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot djodjo, I am going to try it. Hopefully it will work